# How to increase resolution to 1920x1080 for Fedora 25 workstation

Tags: fedora, resolution

It looks like the max resolution is only 1600x900, even though my monitor can handle 1920x1080.  How can i force a higher resolution?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your video card can support the higher resolutions? Have you installed the correct drivers for that video card?

Answer (score 9):

More of a workaround than a solution: You can use `xrandr` to add an additional resolution to the display.

First use `xrandr` to get a list of the displays, my display is called `LVDS`:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 600, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS connected primary 1024x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 223mm x 125mm
   1024x600      60.00*+
   800x600       59.86  
   848x480       59.66  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x480       59.38  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Then calculate a modeline for the resolution you like:

```
$ cvt 1366 768
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

Afterwards use xrandr to add the resolution to the display:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode LVDS "1368x768_60.00"
```

And activate the new resolution:

```
$ xrandr --output LVDS --mode "1368x768_60.00"
```

You can add these three `xrandr` commands to your `.xprofile` to execute them on start.