# X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, xrandr, resolution

I'm running Fedora 31 in VirtualBox 6.1 on a Windows 10 machine and trying to get 1920x1080 resolution. I followed the advice in [How to increase resolution to 1920x1080 for Fedora 25 workstation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348974/how-to-increase-resolution-to-1920x1080-for-fedora-25-workstation), but I get the error below.

```
[oyv@localhost ~]$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1680x1050     59.85*+
   1400x1050     59.86  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
[oyv@localhost ~]$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
[oyv@localhost ~]$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
[oyv@localhost ~]$ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "1920x1080_60.00"
[oyv@localhost ~]$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

Comment: Are the VirtualBox `GuestAdditions` installed?